# How can I remove padded NULL bytes using SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string

If data is inserted this way,

```
insert into `t` (`date`, `data`) values ( now(), lpad('Hello', 4096, CHAR(0x00)));
```

How do you retrive it removing NULL characters from `data` column. I am infact looking for something that does the reverse of what `LPAD` does.

The table definition is,

```
create table `t` (
    `id` int auto_increment,
    `date` datetime,
    `data` blob,
    primary key (`id`)
);
```

Generalized question is, How can I remove an specific character from either beginning or ending of a string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [trim()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), which comes in 3 flavours:

```
select trim(leading CHAR(0x00) from data)
```

or

```
select trim(trailing CHAR(0x00) from data)
```

or

```
select trim(both CHAR(0x00) from data)
```

Comment: OMG! every time I search the manual I ended up reading [LTRIM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim)

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use TRIM, as in;

```
select id, date, trim(trailing char(0) from data) as data from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very useful. I dump queries into Excel frequently using SQLyog.  I ran into this issue exporting a mediumtext field and the trim/trailing function as used here made my exports functional.