# MySQL VARCHAR Type won't CONVERT to Integer

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

I have a column of data of type `VARCHAR`, that I want to `CONVERT` or `CAST` to an integer (my end goal is for all of my data points to be integers). However, all the queries I attempt return values of `0`.

My data looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I run either of the following queries:

```
SELECT CONVERT(data, BINARY) FROM table
SELECT CONVERT(data, CHAR) FROM table
```

My result is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

No surprises there.  However, if I run either of these queries:

```
SELECT CONVERT(data, UNSIGNED) FROM table
SELECT CONVERT(data, SIGNED) FROM table
```

My result is:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

I've searched SO and Google all over for an answer to this problem, with no luck, so I thought I would try the pros here.

EDIT/UPDATE

I ran some additional queries on the suggestions from the comments, and here are the results:

```
data LENGTH(data) LENGTH(TRIM(data)) ASCII(data)
1    3            3                  0
2    3            3                  0
3    3            3                  0
4    3            3                  0
5    3            3                  0
```

It appears that I have an issue with the data itself.  For anyone coming across this post: my solution at this point is to `TRIM` the excess from the data points and then `CONVERT` to `UNSIGNED`.  Thanks for all of the help!

FURTHER EDIT/UPDATE

After a little research, turns out there were hidden `NULL` bytes in my data.  The answer to this question helped out: [How can I remove padded NULL bytes using SELECT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938081/how-can-i-remove-padded-null-bytes-using-select-in-mysql)

Comment: worked fine for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a15ec4/1/3 . Your table isn't actually called table is it?  makes me think you have a data problem.  sure there's not a return or space in the data somewhere?

Comment: @xQbert no, just an example name.  It's a really bizarre issue; I'm not sure what could be the cause of this one.  Is it possible that the data is corrupted somehow?  I'm just guessing at this point.

Comment: show us your create table statement

Comment: you could look up the ascii value for all data and see if you get the values for 0-9... if not you know you have a data integrity issue or just do a length and if > 1 you know you have a data problem.

Comment: @xQbert great suggestion - is there a quick way of accomplishing that via SQL that you know of?  If not I'll research it further.

Comment: `select length(data) as mLEN from table having mlen>1` for length

Comment: What does `SELECT data, LENGTH(data), LENGTH(TRIM(data)), ASCII(data) FROM table` return?  Are you using multibyte character encoding?

Comment: `select ascii(data) from foo where ascii(data) not between 48 and 57` for ascii characters... not 0-9

Comment: @BaconBits I ran those queries you recommended and got the above results (added to question).  Thanks for the suggestion!  If you put your suggestion in an answer, I'll vote up/accept to give you some cred.

Comment: @xQbert I ran your ASCII query and found my issue.  Thanks for all of your help!  If you put your thoughts in an answer, I'll vote up/accept to give you some credit for your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `SELECT data, LENGTH(data), LENGTH(TRIM(data)), ASCII(data) FROM table` return? It's possible your numeric strings aren't just numeric strings.

Alternately, are you using multi-byte character encoding?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the query you have is fine; as it worked for me: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a15ec4/1/3.

Makes me think you have a data problem. Are you sure there's not a return or space in the data somewhere?

you can check the data by trying to do a length or a ascii on the data to see if you have more than expected:

`select ascii(data) from foo where ascii(data) not between 48 and 57` or

`select length(data) as mLEN from table having mlen>1` for length.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the correct form:

```
SELECT CAST(data AS UNSIGNED) FROM test;
SELECT CAST(data AS SIGNED) FROM test;
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/8c481/1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately, both of these queries returned `0` for each data point.  This may be a really bizarre issue.

Comment: @Daniel, do the values also contain some unwanted space? Can you copy the values and paste them in a notepad and check for extra white spaces? That might be the issue.

Comment: That's a great suggestion @Eduard Uta, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Spaces can't be the problem since they don't affect `CAST` and `CONVERT` - See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/13d35/2

Comment: what about a hard return?

Answer (score 0):

Try these syntax

```
SELECT CONVERT(data, UNSIGNED INTEGER) FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(data AS UNSIGNED) FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, although: `SELECT CONVERT(data, UNSIGNED INTEGER) FROM table` gives the same result of `0`, and `SELECT CONVERT(data AS UNSIGNED) FROM table` yields a syntax error.  I think the `AS` syntax only works with `CAST()`.

Comment: Yes sorry the 2nd should have been cast